# checking text field value length

Tags: javascript

I am trying to see if the text field length is at least a certain length.  here is my code:

```
<form name="form2" id="form2" onsubmit="return validate()">
length 4: <input type="text" name = "t" id="t" />
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script>
function validate() {
    document.write("good");
    submitFlag = true;
    if(document.form2.t.value.length!=4){
        submitFlag=false;
        alert("ivalid length - 4 characters needed!");
    }
    return submitFlag;
}
</script>
```

when I click submit, nothing happens.

Comment: You're using `document.write()` in wrong context again...

Answer (score 5):

Change your submit button to type="submit".  The form is never getting submitted so the validate function isn't being called.

Answer (score 1):

The input type needs to be "submit"

```
<form name="form2" id="form2" onsubmit="return validate()">
   length 4: <input type="text" name = "t" id="t" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />  <!--INPUT TYPE MUST BE SUBMIT -->
    </form>

    <script>
    function validate() {
        document.write("good");
        submitFlag = true;
        if(document.form2.t.value.length!=4){
            submitFlag=false;
            alert("ivalid length - 4 characters needed!");
        }
        return submitFlag;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want greater than or equal to (>=), instead of not equal to (!=) if you want "at least a certain length"

Answer (score 0):

Your button should be

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

otherwise the `onsubmit` event will not occur.  Also, use `console.log()` for debugging, rather than `document.write()`.

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/GHqmV/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted various errors:

- don't use `document.write()`, it will overwrite the currently open document
- `form2` is no property of `document`. You may use `document.forms.form2`, but `document.getElementById("t")` is simpler here
- Your expression doesn't check for "at least 4", it checks for "exactly 4".
- Your button won't submit anything. Change it to `<button type="submit">` or `<input type="submit" />`
- you could specify a [`pattern=".{4}"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute) for the input or give it a `required` attribute

Comment: 1. what do i use in place? just write the message to a div?  2. form2 is the name/id for the form.  i guess this tutorial book that i'm using must be really old....  3. is there any advantage to using javascript for min/max length?

Comment: Yes, after the document is loaded you need to manipulate the DOM; for example manipulate the innerText of a div. @HTML5 validation: The advantage is you won't need javascript (in modern browsers). BTW: min/max are only for numbers

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues that you have. 1) You need to make your input a submit button and 2) you need to remove your `document.write()` statement.  Change your code to the following ([or see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Hnq/)):

```
<form name="form2" id="form2" onsubmit="return validate()">
length 4: <input type="text" name = "t" id="t" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script>
function validate() {
    submitFlag = true;
    if(document.form2.t.value.length!=4){
        submitFlag=false;
        alert("ivalid length - 4 characters needed!");
    }
    return submitFlag;
}
</script>​​​​
```

You were pretty close, but you could use some clean-up on that code (Note: I did not provide any).

Answer (score 0):

You should also add a maxlength attribute to your text input, it'll help the user.

```
<form name="form2" id="form2" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <input type="text" name="t" id="t" maxlength="4"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        if ( document.getElementById("t").value.length != 4 )
        {
            alert( "Invalid length, must be 4 characters" );
            return false;
        }   
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this function

```
var a = txtTelNo1.value;
            if (a.length != 10) {
                alert('Phone number should be 10 characters');
                return false;
            }
```