# how to make submit button can be clicked if the validation is in accordance with the model ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Im using rails 5.

I have a model named "Post"
and post has 2 params :

```
validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}, :uniqueness => true
validates :body, presence: true, length: {minimum: 30}
```

And in Post Form :

```
<%= f.text_field :title %>
<%= f.text_field :body %>
<%= f.submit "Save"%>
```

My Question is : 
How to make this submit button can only be clicked when the validation is in accordance with the model (I mean like the submit button cannot be clicked if `:title` is less than 5 characters)

Comment: for model validation to be in effect, you will have to submit the request somehow anyway, no? You may instead be looking to add some frontend validations

Comment: You can only achieve that by using JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

I found a great tutorial for your case. Try [this](http://www.dailysmarty.com/posts/how-to-integrate-client-side-validation-to-check-for-uniqueness-in-rails) for steps and also [client_side_validations](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations) gem can be used to validate your form easily from client side. (**Tip**: Use callback functions to disable your submit button)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write client-side validation to enable the submit option.

```
 <%= f.text_field :title, required: true %>
```

In the above example `require: true` will to validate the presence. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216933/checking-text-field-value-length) for length validation through javascript.

Answer (score -1):

i already found the solution..

here's my codes:

```
<%= form_for(post, html: { multipart: true, :onsubmit => "return validate();" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, id: 'text' %>
  <%= f.text_field :body %>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" >
<% end %>
```

and i put this js script on bottom of my form :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate()
        {
            if ( document.getElementById("text").value.length <= 5 )
            {
                alert( "Title is too short, must be at least 5 characters" );
                return false;
            }   
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

Thx to all of You guys.. really appreciate it..